# R class not found after configuring applicationId by product flavors

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I have two flavors in my app and I want a different `applicationId` for each one. This is what I have:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mycompany.app"
    //more stuff
}

...

productFlavors {
    firstflavor {
        applicationIdSuffix '.first'
        //more stuff
    }
    secondflavor {
        applicationIdSuffix '.second'
        //more stuff
    }
}
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, I have `package="com.mycompany.app"`, and all the code is under that package.

When I assemble it with, say, flavor `firstflavor`, I get this error:

> Error:The generated com.mycompany.app.first.R class cannot be
>   found

Shouldn't `R.class` be generated under `com.company.app` instead of `com.company.app.first`?

How is it package related to application id?

If I remove the application id flavor configuration (`applicationIdSuffix`), everything works properly.

**EDIT**

I have read this [here](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/package-name-vs-application-id/):

> If the BuildConfig.java and R.java files was set to the applicationId
>   rather than the package name, then the code which referenced these
>   would need to have different imports for different build variants – in
>   other words you would need to have separate source sets (with huge
>   amounts of duplication) for your different build flavors in order to
>   access these. This would have some quite profound implications for the
>   maintainability of our code.

However, error says that `com.mycompany.app.first.R` cannot be found. But, `com.mycompany.app.first` is the application id, not the package name! Why is that?

I'm using Android Annotations 3.3.2

Comment: It should be built automatically but sometimes android studio does screw up. The invalidate helps as it basically rebuilds all the indexes and generates an R file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/1888). As I said, I'm using Android Annotations, so I needed to configure package name in apt plugin:

```
apt {
    arguments {
        //more things
        resourcePackageName "com.mycompany.app" //add this line
    }
}
```

and everything is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Use the file menu and do an invalidate caches and restart.

Use the invalidate and restart option there.

It'll rebuild the indexes and solve your issue. If that doesn't work, also do a clean build from the build menu and there'll been a gradle sync button on your toolbar, use that. Mostly the invalidate and restart should solve your issue of you don't have any other errors

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just invalidated and restarted and still not working.

Comment: What error are you seeing?  You've not added dimension to the flavour so that might be an issue too... Could you paste the errors your see in your gradle console

Comment: Oh and paste your build.gradle file